# How can I run tmux commands on an aws machine from a single ssh command on my local machine?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, tmux

If I run:

`ssh -i permissions_file.pem -t ubuntu@<AWS_Public_IP> 'bash run_tmux_experiment.sh'`

Nothing runs on the aws machine. I tmux ls and no server is running. If I ssh into this machine and then run "bash run_tmux_experiment.sh" then it works.

For a little more info, here is approximately what run_tmux_experiment.sh looks like:

> `#!/bin/bash
>   tmux \
>      new-session "python long_expirement.py"
>      detach-client`

Comment: please try the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should post more detailed information about from which system are you connecting (would differ from windows (yes it has ssh.exe) and unix based OS).

For sake of simplicity I presume you are connecting from Unix based OS:

To run a bash script you don't need to specify the shell.  The user `ubuntu` should have it as set default shell.

To specify default shell you can do:
it in these ways:

- run `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash ubuntu`
- edit .bashrc
- edit /etc/passwd (after the last `:` enter your shell as `:/bin/bash`
  e.g. `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

Now to your actual issue:

You can run it multiple ways.  I'll post only 2 in my eyes the best ones:

- run local script on remote machine - no need to actually manually upload the script  (note: no need to setup the default shell then):
  `ssh -i permissions_file.pem -t ubuntu@AWS_Public_IP 'bash -s' < /your/local/path/run_tmux_experiment.sh`
- if you still want to run the remote script you can do it the following way: 
   `ssh -i permissions_file.pem -t ubuntu@AWS_Public_IP './remote/path/foo.sh'`